# SAP B1 Error - Form - Not found [66000-9]

Tags: c#, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

```
case "2305":
{
     SAPbouiCOM.Form oForm = Support.oApplication.Forms.GetForm("142", 1);

     FrmPedidoCompra frmPedidoCompra = new FrmPedidoCompra(oForm);
                        
     frmPedidoCompra.CreateButtonNovaDataEntrega();
     break;
}
```

I have this code and i want to know why it returns the message: Form - Not found  [66000-9].
142 is the type of Purchase Order, isn't it?

I tried everything. Trade 142 by 139 for example, but the error continues.

Answer (score 1):

Is this form already opened? Because this method does not open new one it just returns exsisting one if there is any.

From documentation:

> Each SAP Business One form has a type, which is a unique ID for the
> form. For example, the type of the Purchase Order form is 142.
>
> Each form can be open multiple times, and the application keeps a
> counter for each form type of the number of open instances. To get the
> number of forms open of the same type, use Form.TypeCount. Form
> objects pointing to different instances of the same type form have the
> same value in the TypeCount field.
>
> To access a specific instance of a specific form type, use the
> Forms.GetForm method.